# Why this unexpected composer version result?

Tags: php, composer-php, semantic-versioning

I have the following two packages

Package : `"my/package"`
Releases `0.8.9, 0.8.8, 0.8.7, 0.8.6, 0.8.5, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.4, ...`

Package : `"my/package2"`
Releases: `0.1.1, 0.1.0`

My default composer.json config with strange behavior installs:

```
{
  "minimum-stability" : "stable",
  "require" :           {
    "my/package" :    "*",
    "my/package2" :   "*"
  }
}
```

Result:

- `"my/package"@0.8.0`
- `"my/package2"@0.1.1`

If I change the config to the following:

```
{
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "minimum-stability" : "dev",
  "require" :           {
    "my/package" :    "*",
    "my/package2" :   "*"
  }
}
```

Result:

- `"my/package"@0.8.9`
- `"my/package2"@0.1.1`

why installs my default config `"my/package"@0.8.0` and not `@0.8.9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer in my case is realy simple:

The package `"my/package"` has since version 0.8.1 a requirement to `"my/package3"@dev-master` wich also classify `"my/package"`as not stable.